# Display interface - wrong parameter

Tags: switch, hp

I couldn't check the HP interface status. i've run display interface  and it shows wrong parameter. See below.

```
XGE2/0/14            UP   1G(a)   F(a)   T  

<SW1>display interface GE2/0/14
                              ^
 % Wrong parameter found at '^' position.
```

The switch model is A5820X-24XG-SFP+

Comment: Please provide the model of your switch and firmware/software version your switch is running.

Comment: model of the switch is - A5820X-24XG-SFP+

Comment: From what I see in the documentation, it appears that there needs to be a space between the interface type and the interface number. For example, `display interface xge 2/0/14`. You may also be able to try `display interface ?` to show a list of acceptable commands and proper syntax`.

Comment: thanks jesse, tried to used display interface Ten-GigabitEthernet 2/0/14 it worked! thanks again

Comment: good deal. I’ll submit that as an answer since it solved your issue.

Comment: As a general help, you can hit the `?` key at any point to have the switch display the currently available options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax for the command includes a space between the interface type and interface number, so the properly formatted command is:

```
display interface Ten-GigabitEthernet 2/0/14
```